# Error "out of range: requested -1 but maximum is 12"

Tags: javascript, react-native

After starting the application for the first time, when entering an option from a list, gives me this error.
This occurs only at the first opening of the application. Then stop showing up.
The error is linked to an index that is being called with the value -1/12, but there is no negative index.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQNxv.png)

useEffect, call function scrollTo

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (users !== undefined) getAPIinfo();
 scrollTo();
}, [isLogin, users]);
```

code where the indicator is used, and is giving error

```
const scrollTo = () => {
  if (headerSlider.current && isLogin.secondaryUser) {
    const nextIndex = users.findIndex(
      (elem) => elem.id === isLogin.secondaryUser.id
    );
    console.log("nextIndex: ", nextIndex);
    headerSlider?.current?.scrollToIndex({
      animated: true,
      index: nextIndex,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Whatever you're searching for isn't being found in the array so the default value of `-1` is returned instead. [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: Could be this: when using ===, the types on both sides must be the same for a match. E.g. `"7" === 7` will produce **`false`**.

Comment: I don't think that's it, because it's working for all options, except for the first option just at the beginning of the application... after the start, the application always works normally.

Comment: This code square is assigning the nextIndex the link number between the option and the following screen, taken when the elem.id is equal to the secondary user id.
Now when I start the "app" for the first time, you are assigning the -1 index to the first option, and the indexes always start at 0.
After navigating the application the -1 index, it appears to update to the correct index.